# How do I connect this function to my connectButton?

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth, qt5, qpushbutton

I am trying to connect the addDevice() function from my Device class to my connectButton on my GUI. However no matter how I try and code the connect function, it does not work. Currently it is giving me the error:
primary expression expected before the ',' token.

I have tried the follow syntaxes:

```
connect(ui->connectButton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),d,SLOT(startDeviceDiscovery()));
connect(ui->connectButton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),d,&Device::startDeviceDiscovery());
connect(ui->connectButton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(startDeviceDiscovery()));
connect(ui->connectButton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,Device::startDeviceDiscovery());
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QObject>
#include <QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent>
#include <QtBluetooth>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "device.h"
#include "deviceinfo.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

Device d;

connect(ui->connectButton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),Device,SLOT(startDeviceDiscovery()));

//
.
.
.

}
```

Device.h

```
#ifndef DEVICE_H
#define DEVICE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <qbluetoothglobal.h>
#include <qbluetoothlocaldevice.h>
#include <QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent>
#include <QLowEnergyController>
#include <QBluetoothDeviceInfo>
#include <QBluetoothServiceInfo>
#include "deviceinfo.h"
#include <QList>
#include <QVariant>


class Device : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Device(QObject *parent = 0);

QVariant name();
~Device();

signals:
    void address(QVariant);

public slots:
void startDeviceDiscovery();
void connectDeivce(const QString &address);

};

#endif // DEVICE_H
```

Comment: Why are you connecting to `SIGNAL(clicked(bool))` with `bool` parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a connect you need a pointer, and you created your Device on the constructor, this means that just after the connect is used, constructor would finish, and this would destroy your device, disconnecting the function.

Correct syntax:

```
 Device *myDevice = new Device();

connect(
    ui->connectButton, // the pointer of the signal emitter
    &QPushButton::clicked, // the signal you are interested
    myDevice,              // the pointer to receiving end
    &Device::startDeviceDiscovery); // what you wanna trigger
```

you mixed every possibility in your tests, but in all of them you treated the slot as a method, calling the () operator. you can't call the call operator, on the connect you are passing the pointer of the method to a function that will call that for you when the time is right.